# How to define a layer with multiple input tensors(tensors with different shape)

Tags: python, keras-layer

I want to define a layer that can have multiple inputs. I found an example on keras doc here
https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/
But i don't understand the call function. 
e.g. if i want to give *a* an assignment  like input layer 1, b is assigned with input layer  2. How to define the call?

Answer (score 0):

Keras already supports multi input architecture through its functional API. You can define a neural network with multiple inputs as explained in this [article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/).